# Breaking up CPT output into two columns

Tags: custom-post-types, php

I have the following code. I have a left div and a right div. How would I edit the below code to pull the first X CPT data and put it in the right column, and the next XX number CPT data to put in the left column? Right now I am just printing same query in the two columns. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="generic-page-container clearfix smallwidth">
    <div class="content_left">
        <?php
            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'testimonials', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
              //the_title();
              echo '<div class="testimonials_block">';
              the_content();
              echo '</div>';
            endwhile;
        ?>
    </div><!--/#content_left -->
    <div class="content_right">
        <?php
            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'testimonials', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
              //the_title();
              echo '<div class="testimonials_block">';
              the_content();
              echo '</div>';
            endwhile;
        ?>
    </div><!--/#content_right -->
</div><!--#generic-page-container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one query and the class property `WP_Query::$current_post` the index of which will beging at `0`.

As we iterate over the available posts, we check the `$current_post` index value `+1` to bring it to par with the `$posts_per_page` value.

If the `$current_post` is less than half (5 in this case) we push the markup onto the array `$content['left']` and vice versa the right side `$content['right']` when we are on posts 6 through 10.

Finally, where you need the markup/content, we implode the array and echo it...

```
<?php

    $posts_per_page = 10;
    $content        = array('left' => '', 'right' => '');

    $args           = array( 
        'post_type'      => 'testimonials', 
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page 
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

      $column = ($loop->current_post+1) < ($posts_per_page/2) ? 'left' : 'right';

      $content[$column] .= '<div class="testimonials_block">' . get_the_content() . '</div>';

    endwhile;

?>

<div class="generic-page-container clearfix smallwidth">
    <div class="content_left"><?php echo implode('', $column['left']);?></div>
    <div class="content_right"><?php echo implode('', $column['right']);?></div>
</div><!--#generic-page-container -->
```

There's other ways to tackle this, this is just but one...

Comment: i don't want to show the same CPT twice. i want 1-10 on right side and 11-20 on left side for example

Comment: change `$posts_per_page = 10;` to `$posts_per_page = 20;`

Comment: seems the 'implode' is showing an error for me. i tried wrapping it in a var_dump with no success.

Comment: @HollerTrain that's because there was an error in my syntax, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Don't run the query twice. Use `get_posts($args)` instead of `new WP_Query`. Then use `array_slice()` to generate to arrays of equal length and loop through them that way.

`array_slice()` help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393028/how-can-i-take-an-array-divide-it-by-two-and-create-two-lists